# Loging on frontend failed with no errors

Tags: magento2, login, cookie, sessions

For a few hours I could not login on frontend. (on local domain https://www.magento2.loc, magento 2.2.5, developer mode).
If I enter wrong username or password, yes, I receive error message. 
With correct credentials it just reloaded the login page, that's all. 
Googling around did  not help.
I tried all possible settings with cookies and sessions, cleared generated, cache and sessions directories, disabled all modules in app/code and switched to blank theme. The backend, by the way, worked normally. I could log in and out to the dashboard.

The problem was solved by itself when I restarted the computer (MAC, El Capitan) and crossed my fingers.

The question is what could it be? And how to prevent it in production environment?

Comment: Did this happen in google chrome, actually it had been with me also with chrome. You can check issue [Customer login not working in chrome & Edge browser but proper working in Firefox browser in Magento 2.2.2 #13423](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13423) and [Customer registration and login doesn't work with Browser Chrome #14295](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14295)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue is regarding session, by default session store in files in Magento, you can try to change it to DB for your local instance and try if your problem resolve or not. You can change session storage location from

```
app->etc->env.php
```

Replace this:

```
'session' => [
        'save' => 'files'
    ]
```

With :

```
'session' => [
            'save' => 'db'
        ]
```

On production I think you have to store session on Redis server
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/redis-session.html

Comment: That's good idea, and I have not tried this yet. Now I'll be waiting the problem to appear again as I do not know what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Set a `domaine cookie` in : `Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Default Cookie Settings`
2. `Use HTTP Only` > Yes
3. Cookie Lifetime > `3600`
4. Clean the content of `var/session`
5. Clean and flush the cache.